# Macro script to Apply to Button for Formatting in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I've been searching the world over and I cannot create nor find a macro for a very basic function that I need.  All I want to do is to be able to compare column A with column B and if they do not match, highlight red. I need this in a macro because I want to assign it to a button. I can do it with conditional formatting but not in VB. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Hi @flyc do you only want the match to happen if the entire columns match or items in the row (i.e. if a5 and b5 match highlight it)

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283163/removing-phrases-like-i-looked-everywhere-on-the-internet-and-i-did-not-find-an) regarding the use of narrative [hyperbole](https://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=dictionary%3Ahyperbole) in questions.

Comment: Hi James. I want the two fields to highlight if they do not match and that's for the entire column. Sometimes the report will have 500 entries and sometimes it will have over 1000. It's different everytime so I have to apply it to the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, data requiring this type of action would have column header labels and I will assume that.

```
Sub red_dupes()
    Dim a As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
            .Columns("A:B").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            For Each a In .Columns(1).Cells
                If a.Value2 <> a.Offset(0, 1).Value2 Then
                    a.Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next a
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This particular sub removes all previous colour *Fill* before looping through the cells in column A and marking all A→B non-matches with a red color fill. Do NOT use if you want to retain existing color fills.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for that code. I ran the script but its getting a runtime error on line 3 . It says subscript out of range. I'll continue to tweak it to see if I can get the error resolved but my VB skills are nil.